# QOBJECT macro declared

Tags: qt, qobject

I have declared QOBJECT macro but still its calling the function without passing the QObject object

Here is my code
keyusermanagertest.cpp

```
#define private public
#define protected public
#include "keyusermanagertest.h"
#include "storageusermanager.h"
#include "keyusermanager.h"
#include "alkuser.h"
#undef protected
#undef private

#include <QDebug>
#include <QtTest/QtTest>

QTEST_MAIN(KeyUserManagerTest)

void KeyUserManagerTest::init()
{

}

void KeyUserManagerTest::cleanup()
{
}

void KeyUserManagerTest::test_initialization()
{
// Already tested under BackendTest::test_initialization()

}

void KeyUserManagerTest::settersAndGetters()
{
    AlkUser userInfo;
    QString user="Puneet Goyal";
    StorageUserManager* storageuser=new StorageUserManager();
    KeyUserManager* keyuser=new KeyUserManager(storageuser);
    keyuser->updateUserData(user,userInfo);
    qDebug()<<"UPDATION DONE!!!!";
// Now setting the rest of the details for user Puneet Goyal using AlkUser Object

    userInfo.setName("Puneet");
    userInfo.setContact("21897121");
    userInfo.setType("savings");
    userInfo.setAccount("123456789");   
    userInfo.setAmount("100000");

// Now retrieving all the user details using KeyUserManager Object
    QVariant vari=keyuser->getUserInfo("Puneet Goyal");

}
```

keyusermanagertest.h

```
#ifndef KEYUSERMANAGERTEST_H
#define KEYUSERMANAGERTEST_H

#include <QtCore/QObject>

class KeyUserManager;

class KeyUserManagerTest : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

private slots:

  void init();
  void cleanup();
  void test_initialization();
  void settersAndGetters();
};

#endif
```

Its compile output is as follows"
/home/puneet/puneet/office/alkimia/payment/backend/keyusermanagertest.cpp: In member function ‘void KeyUserManagerTest::settersAndGetters()’:
/home/puneet/puneet/office/alkimia/payment/backend/keyusermanagertest.cpp:52: error: no matching function for call to ‘StorageUserManager::StorageUserManager()’
/home/puneet/puneet/office/alkimia/payment/backend/storageusermanager.h:41: note: candidates are: StorageUserManager::StorageUserManager(QObject*)
/home/puneet/puneet/office/alkimia/payment/backend/storageusermanager.h:37: note:                 StorageUserManager::StorageUserManager(const StorageUserManager&)
/home/puneet/puneet/office/alkimia/payment/backend/keyusermanagertest.cpp:53: error: no matching function for call to ‘KeyUserManager::KeyUserManager(StorageUserManager*&)’
/home/puneet/puneet/office/alkimia/payment/backend/keyusermanager.h:44: note: candidates are: KeyUserManager::KeyUserManager(StorageUserManager*, QObject*)
/home/puneet/puneet/office/alkimia/payment/backend/keyusermanager.h:41: note:                 KeyUserManager::KeyUserManager(const KeyUserManager&)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add constructor to your KeyUserManagerTest -
in header add

```
KeyUserManagerTest (QObject* parent=0);
```

and in cpp

```
KeyUserManagerTest::KeyUserManagerTest(QObject* parent):QObject(parent){};
```

QOBJECT macro does not create constructor for you!

Comment: thanks, but now its giving me an error that
error: return type specification for constructor invalid

Comment: hmmm... then something is wrong with your constructor. Is it declared public?

Comment: yes its public

public:
void KeyUserManagerTest (QObject* parent=0);

Comment: remove void that is constructor it has no return type

Comment: I got my mistake.......I had to do that in the KeyUserManager class
and I had not equated it to 0